# Git slow on large repo

Tags: git, performance, version-control, project-management

I have a large git repo on my drive and git operations on it take a very long time. I've noticed that it has a pack file of around 800mb. Would it improve the performance if I were to unpack that file?

Comment: Try not to commit binary files to git. If you have to commit large files, consider looking at git-lfs.

Comment: Is this on Windows or on Linux? Unfortunately git tends to be *significantly* slower on Windows machines than on Linux (I don't quite know why though).

Comment: @evolutionxbox This repository is actually a huge project. There's nothing other than code in it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It's on linux, ext4.

Comment: How many files are there in a checkout and what operations take long (and what exactly is "long", use `time` to verify how long it actually takes).

Comment: @JoachimSauer First run takes around 30 secs. There are around 33000 files in a checkout.

Comment: The goal of pack files is to be *faster and smaller than* individual loose objects. This goal is not always achieved and if you look at what's going on with Git 2.24 and later, there's some performance work when you have many pack files (it's not a matter of how big they are but rather how many you have). (Ext4 itself is in general a bit slow; the Ceph people generally recommend XFS for a combination of speed and reasonable reliability.)

Answer (score 3):

if your repo contains big files, you should consider using Git LFS : https://git-lfs.github.com/